# JIRA gadget REST module wont give value back

Tags: java, rest, jira

I am trying to develop an **Atlassian JIRA gadget**, that will get values from *.java* files using the **REST module**. To manage this, I read the JIRA documentation (for [REST](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/REST+Plugin+Module), [gadgets](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Writing+Gadgets+for+JIRA) and many more) and took the examples. So I got i.a. following code:

gadget.xml: 
...

```
   <Content type="html" view="profile">
   <![CDATA[
#requireResource("com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common")
#includeResources()

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var gadget = AJS.Gadget({
            baseUrl: "__ATLASSIAN_BASE_URL__",
            useOauth: "/rest/gadget/1.0/currentUser",
            view: {
                   template: function(args) {
          var gadget = this;       
          var userDetails = AJS.$("<h1/>").text("Hello, "+args.fred.firstName);       
          gadget.getView().html(userDetails);
            },
                  args: [{
                        key: "fred",
                        ajaxOptions: function() {
                            return {
                                url: "/rest/My_Dashboard/1.0/users"
                            };
                        }
                    }]
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
]]>
```

RestHelloWorldService.java:

```
package com.atlassian.jira.plugin.tutorial;

import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.tutorial.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("/")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class RestHelloWorldService { 
    @GET
    @Path("users")
    public Response getUncompletedUsers() {
        return Response.ok(new User("Fred","Bloggs")).build();
    }
}
```

And the User.java:

```
package com.atlassian.jira.plugin.tutorial;

import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.tutorial.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;


@XmlRootElement
public class User
{
    @XmlElement
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement
    private String lastName;

    // This private constructor isn't used by any code, but JAXB requires any
    // representation class to have a no-args constructor.
    private User() { }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

BUILD SUCCESS!

But my gadget still shows nothing. And the data are at the URL location:

```
<user>
<firstName>Fred</firstName>
<lastName>Bloggs</lastName>
</user>
```

What could be wrong?
I am out of ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

I had to add two lines in the gadget.xml to set the contentType and the dataType to JSON:

```
...args: [{
         key: "fred",
         ajaxOptions: function() {
                            return {
                                url: "/rest/My_Dashboard/1.0/users", 
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                dataType: "json",
                            };
                        }
                    }]
```

Thanks for the answer anyway!